# how to parse multiple lines using ruby treetop?

Tags: ruby, parsing, treetop

I am new to `ruby` and `treetop`.

I went through [this tutorial](http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/a-quick-intro-to-writing-a-parser-using-treetop.html) and came up with the following set of rules.

```
grammar Sexp

  rule body
    commentPortString *(I am stuck here)*
  end

  rule interface
    space? (intf / intfWithSize) space? ('\n' / end_of_file) <Interface>
  end

  rule commentPortString
    space? '//' space portString space? ('\n' / end_of_file) <CommentPortString>
  end

  rule portString
    'Port' space? '.' <PortString>
  end

  rule expression
    space? '(' body ')' space? <Expression>
  end

  rule intf
    (input / output) space wire:wireName space? ';' <Intf>
  end

  rule intfWithSize
    (input / output) space? width:ifWidth space? wire:wireName space? ';' <IntfWithSize>
  end

  rule input
    'input'
  end

  rule output
    'output'
  end

  rule ifWidth
    '[' space? msb:digits space? ':' space? lsb:digits ']' <IfWidth>
  end

  rule digits
    [0-9]+
  end

  rule integer
    ('+' / '-')? [0-9]+ <IntegerLiteral>
  end

  rule float
    ('+' / '-')? [0-9]+ (('.' [0-9]+) / ('e' [0-9]+)) <FloatLiteral>
  end

  rule string
    '"' ('\"' / !'"' .)* '"' <StringLiteral>
  end

  rule signalTypeString
    '"' if_sig_name:signalType '"' <SignalTypeString>
  end

  rule signalType
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* (receiveLiteral / transmitLiteral) <SignalType>
  end

  rule receiveLiteral
    '.receive'
  end

  rule transmitLiteral
    '.transmit'
  end

  rule identifier
    [a-zA-Z\=\*] [a-zA-Z0-9_\=\*]* <Identifier>
  end

  rule wireName
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* <WireName>
  end

  rule non_space
    !space .
  end

  rule space
    [\s\t]+
  end

  rule newLine
    [\n\r]+
  end

  rule end_of_file
    !.
  end

end
```

I want the parser to extract out blobs such as the one below. It would always start with `Port.` and end with a blank line.

```
    // Port.
    output        send;
    input         free;
    output        fgcg;
    output[  2:0] state_id;
    output[  1:0] stream_id;
`ifdef SIMULATION
    output[ 83:0] dbg_id;
`endif
```

The rules mentioned above can identify all the lines in the text when passed individually but I am unable to extract out the blob. Also I just want to extract out the matching text and ignore the rest.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: To clarify, you want to extract everything from `\\Port` up to `ifdef` or including the `ifdef` block?

Comment: @JoshVoigts i want to extract till the `endif. it need not end in `endif, but will always end in a blank line. I would have multiple of these blocks and I want to extract all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like below along the lines you're looking for. It's hard to understand your problem fully without a little more information.

The `space` rule includes `\s` which includes `\n` already, so if you're looking for another `\n`, it won't parse correctly. If you modify the `space` rule to be `[^\S\n]+` it will exclude `\n` so you can look for it explicitly.

If you're looking for a completely blank line to end the `Port.` block, you should look explicitly for `"\n" ("\n" / end_of_file)`.

Hope that makes sense...

```
grammar Sexp

  rule body
    commentPortString interface* portEnd
  end

  rule interface
    space? (intf / intfWithSize) space? "\n" <Interface>
  end

  rule commentPortString
    space? '//' space? portString space? "\n" <CommentPortString>
  end

  rule portString
    'Port' space? '.' <PortString>
  end

  # Port block ends with a blank line
  rule portEnd
    "\n" / end_of_file
  end

  rule expression
    space? '(' body ')' space? <Expression>
  end

  rule intf
    (input / output) space wire:wireName space? ';' <Intf>
  end

  rule intfWithSize
    (input / output) space? width:ifWidth space? wire:wireName space? ';' <IntfWithSize>
  end

  rule input
    'input'
  end

  rule output
    'output'
  end

  rule ifWidth
    '[' space? msb:digits space? ':' space? lsb:digits ']' <IfWidth>
  end

  rule digits
    [0-9]+
  end

  rule integer
    ('+' / '-')? [0-9]+ <IntegerLiteral>
  end

  rule float
    ('+' / '-')? [0-9]+ (('.' [0-9]+) / ('e' [0-9]+)) <FloatLiteral>
  end

  rule string
    '"' ('\"' / !'"' .)* '"' <StringLiteral>
  end

  rule signalTypeString
    '"' if_sig_name:signalType '"' <SignalTypeString>
  end

  rule signalType
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* (receiveLiteral / transmitLiteral) <SignalType>
  end

  rule receiveLiteral
    '.receive'
  end

  rule transmitLiteral
    '.transmit'
  end

  rule identifier
    [a-zA-Z\=\*] [a-zA-Z0-9_\=\*]* <Identifier>
  end

  rule wireName
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* <WireName>
  end

  rule non_space
    !space .
  end

  rule space
    [^\S\n]+
  end

  rule newLine
    [\n\r]+
  end

  rule end_of_file
    !.
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Did not know \s included \n. Thought that they are separate.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :)